# How to modify the string using index in C file with MPI?

Tags: c, string, indexing, mpi

I'm trying to encrypt my string so I have a simple code where I need to modify the string by accessing its indices and modify each character in the string. I was running it as a normal file with gcc command at first and it worked but when I try to include it in my C file with MPI then it gives me error.

The expected result will be if the string input is "Hello" then the output will be "Khoor".

```
char str[10] = "Hello";

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
     str[i] = str[i] + 3; //the key for encryption is 3 that is added to ASCII value

printf("\nEncrypted string: %c\n", str);
```

The error:

error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                str[i] = str[i] 
+ 3; //the key for encryption is 3 that i...

Comment: What data type is str ? It should be either char * or char [].

Comment: @FlorinPetriuc sorry I've updated the code, yes it is char[]

Comment: Since it's not a [example] I can just look at the code. It looks OK to me. Do you still get the error on the shown line?

Comment: @Thomas Can you add please the declaration of `i`?

Comment: @RobertS `i` is declared as `int` when it is first used - inside the `for` loop control.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is trivial and the solution is simple! When you want to print a string (character array) with `printf` use the `%s` format specifier; the `%c` format is for a **single** character! So, try this:

```
printf("\nEncrypted string: %s\n", str);
```